# Thymeleaf + Bootstrap configuration

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Currenlty I'm trying to configure my webapp to run with Thymeleaf and Bootstrap, so I created sample **index.html** page to test if it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Bookweb™</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{/bootstrap.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
Hello Bootstrap!
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">This is a success button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">This is a warning button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">This is a danger button</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it looks like this when i run it from server app:
[image]

And this is how it should look like:

[image]

This is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.fitk</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookweb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bookweb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/**");
    }
}
```

Not really sure why it's not loading properly, my folder structure path goes like this :**resources/static/bootstrap.css** for css files.

What is more, I'm nut sure about bootstrap.min.css file. Should it also be included in that path?

Any help would be apprieciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spring site](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) the static resources are mapped by default but in this case the `WebMvcConfig` class has the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and that means that default configuration is switched off.

In order to add the static resources properly and according to the spring site the `addResourceLocations` method should receive a class path location in order to locate the `/resources/static` folder properly.

Please see the following instructions in order to enable your static resources

1. Go to `WebMvcConfig` class and change the parameter value that you send to `addResourceLocations` method to `"classpath:/static/"`

Like this

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

2. Go to index.html and change the reference to bootstrap using thymeleaf

Like this

```
<link th:href="@{/static/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This solution is based on the definition that I read from Spring site of how are declared the locations of Class path resources and as you can see `"classpath:/static/"` is declared but as classpath.

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the css/static resource handler in your configuration?

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/**");
```

Comment: i added it now, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Could you share your entire configuration class?

Comment: Gah, it's been a while since I worked with spring/th, but I'd guess that either your folder structure is bad, or you're referencing the css in a wrong way.. try `th:href="@{bootstrap.css}"` without the forward slash, or as /static/bootstrap.css..

Comment: Instead of security ignoring the resources/**, maybe add it to the configuration? `.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151147/discussion-between-ognjen-misic-and-tyler-durden).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to configure the static folder as resource folder. Just try to add the css the following way if the the css is in the static root folder:  –